# In Mongo 2.6, how can I tell if there are any IP based restrictions?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo v2.6.12 cluster that I can't connect to from a new windows machine.  Using TNC I've confirmed that port 27017 is accessible from the source -> destination.

How can I tell if there are mongo-level restrictions, similar to how mysql would grant privileges to a user from a specific host?

I tried using this:
`db.getUser('portfolio_dev', {showCredentials: true, showPrivileges: true, showAuthenticationRestrictions: true});` but I get an error:

> Error: "showAuthenticationRestrictions" is not a valid argument to usersInfo at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1342

I have tried to see if there is a way in this old version of mongo but can't seem to find anything.

Edit: I have another, more general, question for this same issue: [Mongo cluster connection from .Net 4.8 application timing out with No such host is known error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77238982/mongo-cluster-connection-from-net-4-8-application-timing-out-with-no-such-host).  However, in order to rule out a mongodb level restriction I'm trying to check access, hence this question.

Comment: MongoDB 2.6 became end-of-life in 2016! It's time for an upgrade, I would say.

Comment: That is on the road map

Answer (score 0):

Try to select the collection directly:

```
db.getSiblingDB('admin').getCollection('system.users').find({user: 'portfolio_dev'})
```

Comment: This didn't return any AuthenticationRestrictions; however, I'm not sure that is even a thing in Mongo 2.6.  I was able to track down my issue which was related to cluster configuration (not using FQDN).